# how to merge two texts before drawing them on image

Tags: python-3.x, python-imaging-library

Using Pillow library in python:

so basically I want to make two individuals text draw objects as one draw object so I can draw the two texts in one step and make them more related to each other I can give an example to make it clear let's say I have two draw objects one is the square root symbol and the second is some digit so I want to merge them together before drawing them on image.

```
   first_text = DrawObject.text( (50,50), text="25", fill="black", font=fnt )
   second_text = DrawObject.text( (60,40), text="√", fill="black", font=fnt )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normal way of doing this is to create a small piece of canvas, i.e. empty black image and draw the two characters you want to *"pair up"* beside each other onto the canvas. Now use [Image.paste()](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.paste) to paste that piece of canvas wherever you want the two characters.

For best flexibility, make your canvas background transparent so you can paste it over any other background, and specify the same image to paste **twice** as the parameters to `Image.paste(canvas, box, mask=canvas)` and then it will respect transparency when pasting.